# My Beloved Monster - Who is it about?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, rock

**My Beloved Monster** is a song that has been recorded by the US rock band **Eels**. It's the sixth song from their album **Beautiful freak** which was released in 1996. It became a hit after being included in the soundtrack of 2001 movie **Shrek**.

(Use both headphone ears when listening to the following version)

Or listen to this version (without lyrics on screen) but can hear voice in both ears.

It has a [puzzling set of lyrics](https://genius.com/Eels-my-beloved-monster-lyrics). I'm wondering who or what is this song really about? The apparent interpretation would be that this is about a girlfriend but I've seen that it's a tribute to the [deceased sister of their bandleader Mark Oliver Everett](https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/34839/), but there's no official source regarding that claim. His sister Elizabeth did indeed [committed suicide in 1996](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/music/rockandpopmusic/10783358/Eels-no-one-does-misery-like-Mark-Oliver-Everett.html), the same year this album came out.

Is there any official explanation on the subject of this song?

Comment: +1 just for this being one of my favourite albums of all time;) btw, this version isn't because it's some kind of karaoke mix; the vocal is panned hard-right on the original album track.

Comment: @Tetsujin Great to meet another fan! I added another version below, which has been modified to stream voice in both ears.

Comment: Timeline is against the "sister" theory as according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eels_(band)#Electro-Shock_Blues) "Following the success of Beautiful Freak, E experienced a difficult time in his personal life. His sister committed suicide, and his mother was diagnosed with cancer. These events inspired him to write Electro-Shock Blues"

Answer (score 3):

In his autobiography 'Things the Grandchildren Should Know', E reflects on the show at the [Royal Albert Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_at_Royal_Albert_Hall_(Eels_album)) in London during the *Eels with Strings* tour in 2014.
He writes the following about 'My Beloved Monster' (p. 231, my emphasis):

> I'm thinking about the irrational crush I had on **the girl at the post office back in Virginia**. I'm glad she's not here to hear me utter the embarrassing words I wrote about her.

Earlier on in his book (p. 109), E talks about the conception of the song:

> One of the songs I recorded came about when my friend Jon Brion came over to my house one night. [..] He came over and suggested, as an exercise, that he would go upstairs for thirty minutes to write a song while I  went downstairs for thirty minutes to write a song. [..] I went downstairs, picked up my paisley Telecaster guitar, plugged it into the tape recorder and started singing [..].

As for the girl the song is about (pp. 72-73):

> I developed an irrational and embarrassing crush on a girl who worked at the post office. I only ever made small talk with her while buying stamps or sending mail at her counter, but I was always thinking about her. After months of this, I got the nerve to ask her out. She went out with me the day the space shuttle exploded and let me know that she was engaged. I went home and wrote a song called 'The Girl at the Post Office is Getting Married' and that was that.

---

Just to address the erroneous idea that the song is about E's sister Liz's suicide: this is impossible, as it took place shortly before *Beautiful Freak* was released (as pointed out in the comments by user Angst).
From page 119:

> One night before the album's release, we played a show at the Alligator Lounge [..] I came home after the show and checked my phone messages. There was a message from my mom, who sounded really weird, saying to call her. [..]
> [E.'s mother on the phone with him:] 'She took a bottle of pills and went into a coma ... and she ... she ... she ...'
> There was a long pause. Then, 'she died.'

And as can be gleaned from the lyrics, the song is also quite unsuitable for the love for a sister:

> *My beloved monster is tough,
>
> if she wants **she will disrobe you**.
>
> **But if you lay her down for a kiss**,
>
> her little heart it could explode.*

---

This is one of E's most beloved songs, and he plays it (almost) every show, in a wide variety of ways.
On the *Live at the Town Hall LP* [version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IShs8wrZyXM) from 2006, E included a new verse:

> *When she turns out the light every night,
>
> she don't have a thing to fear.
>
> Although the day didn't go quite right,
>
> there's another chance near.*

Something that shines through in his autobiography, is that E has the tendency to embellish the truth when he wants to get a certain idea across. From this verse it seems the subject of this song also has moved past the post office girl crush.